# Accessing Function App via App Service Authentication from Dynamics 365 Plugin

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-functions, dynamics-365

I am trying to access an Azure Function from Dynamics 365 Plugin via service to service call: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service

This function is protected via **App Service Authentication**.

I created a Function App and enabled  App Service Authentication
 under Platform Features -> Authentication/Authorisation.
I enabled Azure Active Directory as the Auth Provider and set Management mode to Express

[image]

I then got the generated Client ID and Client Secret from the Advanced Mode:

[image]

Apparently this is all that is needed to make a token request for the Azure function based, based on article I need 4 required parameters:

Client ID

Client Secret

Grant Type

Resource

I make the following request to generate a token from a Dynamics 365 Plugin but get the following error:

```
Invalid Plugin Execution Exception: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.InvalidPluginExecutionException: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is provided.\r\nTrace ID: 06ddda7f-2996-4c9b-ab7e-b685ee933700\r\nCorrelation ID: d582e2f2-91eb-4595-b44b-e95f42f2f071\r\nTimestamp: 2018-05-23 06:30:58Z","error_codes":[70002,50012],"timestamp":"2018-05-23 06:30:58Z","trace_id":"06ddda7f-2996-4c9b-ab7e-b685ee933700","correlation_id":"d582e2f2-91eb-4595-b44b-e95f42f2f071"}-The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

My code is :

```
         var tokenendpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/de194c13-5ff7-4085-91c3-ac06fb869f28/oauth2/token";
         var reqstring = "client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("5f315431-e4da-4f68-be77-4e257b1b9295");
         reqstring += "&client_secret=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("/oK7nh8pl+LImBxjm+L7WsQdyILErysOdjpzvA9g9JA=");
         reqstring += "&resource=" + Uri.EscapeUriString("https://keyvaultaccess.azurewebsites.net");
         reqstring += "&grant_type=client_credentials";

         //Token request
         WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(tokenendpoint);
         req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
         req.Method = "POST";
         byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reqstring);
         req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
         System.IO.Stream os = req.GetRequestStream();
         os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
         os.Close();

         //Token response
         HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
         StreamReader tokenreader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
         string responseBody = tokenreader.ReadToEnd();
```

I have made sure that I have the correct Client Secret and have also encoded it as I have read somewhere that '+' and '/' are no good.

I am getting the same error in Postman

Any ideas??

Comment: I have changed my secret to just "Hello" and still no joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reqstring += "&resource=" + Uri.EscapeUriString("https://keyvaultaccess.azurewebsites.net");

Since you set `resource` parameter to `https://keyvaultaccess.azurewebsites.net`, I assumed that you have set the **App ID URI** of your AAD app (clientId equals `5f315431-xxxxxxx-4e257b1b9295`) to `https://keyvaultaccess.azurewebsites.net`. I assume that you could retrieve the access_token, but when accessing your azure function endpoint with the access_token, you got the 401 status code.

You need to modify your advanced management mode for Active Directory Authentication, add `https://keyvaultaccess.azurewebsites.net` to **ALLOWED TOKEN AUDIENCES** or change the `resource` parameter to your AAD clientID when sending the token request for acquiring the access_token.

**Active Directory Authentication configuration:**

[image]

**TEST:**

[image]

**Docode the JWT token to check the aud property:**

[image]

**Access my Azure Function endpoint:**

[image]

**Note:** You need to take care of the Authorization level of your function as follows:

[image]

If you also enable function level authentication, your request sent to azure function needs to have the relevant code parameter in the querystring or set the header `x-functions-key` with the value of your function key, or you may just set the authorization level to Anonymous.

Comment: Hi Bruce, Sorry just noticed your response now, in the end I changed my resource to my client ID and everything worked.